# Index fragmentation SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, indexing

I have problem with my indexes on two tables.

Here is code for creating the tables:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table]
 (
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [IP] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Referrer] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [Domain] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [RegID] [int] NULL,
    [Agent] [nvarchar](500) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ([ID] ASC)
         WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table] 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Table_ID]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [ID]
GO
```

And index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Reg_ID] ON [dbo].[Table]
(
    [RegID] ASC
)
   WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
         SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
         ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And another table with index

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2]
(
    [Table2_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TracID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [F_URL] [nvarchar](1500) NULL,
    [S_URL] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Time] [datetime] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Table2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([Table2_ID] ASC)
        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
              IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
              ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table2] WITH CHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Table2_Table] 
     FOREIGN KEY([TracID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Table] ([Web_Visitor_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table2] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Table2_Table]
GO
```

Index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TracID] ON [dbo].[Table2]
(
    [TracID] ASC
)
     WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
           SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
           ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

In first table I have about 6M rows and in second 8M rows (a couple of thousand each day).

I have problem because indexes are fragmented up to 99% in 4 hours.

I run query (`sys.columns`) to get size in bytes and there are results

```
Table 1                    Table 2
name       bytes           name       bytes
ID          16             ID           4
IP          30             TracID       16
Referrer    2000           F_URL        3000
Domain      200            S_URL        200
RegID       4              Time         8 
Agent       1000
```

Does anyone have some idea witch can help me to fix that fragmentation ?

Comment: scheduled maintenance to rebuild indexes....

Answer (score 0):

Are you SURE you need to defragment?  With proper hardware, fragmentation rarely matters anymore. Many old-school SQL people still recommend it, but in reality in most cases it is a relic of a past.

There are two reasons it has become irrelevant. First, all reads should be cached in RAM (if not, you need more RAM--it's cheap and will give you WAY more bang for the buck than effort spent defragmenting). Second, SSDs eliminate seeks times anyway, so fragmentation is irrelevant. As a result of these two changes, the time spent defragmenting is usually wasted.

Comment: With 99% fragmented indexes I my store procedure works from 0.5 to 5h (depends of time period) but with 0% fragmented indexes it's finis from less than minute to 20 minutes. I first use to fix indexes and after that I will continue to work to optimize store procedures

Comment: Hardware is 8gb of ram, virtual sas disks, and 4core processor

Comment: What is your cache hit ratio and how big is your database?

Comment: We didn't set it so it's default value. Database is about 5gb

Comment: Cache hit ratio isn't something you set.  It's something you measure.  I suspect yours is low and that you really need more RAM for your server.  Looking at this measurement will tell you for sure.  It should be at least 99%, probably more like 99.9%.  If you value your time messing with this more than the cost of the RAM, it will likely be worth it to look into this and upgrade.

Comment: Pls tell me is it ok query for locking cache hit ratio  SELECTobject_name, counter_name, cntr_value
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE [object_name] LIKE '%Buffer Manager%'
AND [counter_name] = 'Buffer cache hit ratio'

Comment: You need to divide the value returned by that query by the value returned by `SELECT object_name, counter_name, cntr_value FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters WHERE [object_name] LIKE '%Buffer Manager%' AND [counter_name] = 'Buffer cache hit ratio base'` to get the actual ratio.

Comment: Result of first query is 61 and for second is 64

Comment: That's only 95% which is terrible (no surprise you're having performance problems).  However, those numbers are very low.  Did you restart the server recently?  Have you run your problem query since the last restart?  Try running those queries right after your problem query.

Comment: James, tell me what is your suggestion to do with server to fix it?

Comment: Add memory to the server until the buffer cache hit ratio (divided by the base) is above 99.9%.  Once you do that, your query slowness will go away because the entire index will be cached.

Comment: A down vote on the only answer which was up voted by others with no explanation or refutation is not cool.

Comment: I don't know did you min on me, but I'm not for sure, also I haven't reputation to vote because it's less than 15